# Arquivo corrompido ao salvar no bd - PHP

Tags: php, arquivo

preciso de ajuda.

Estou com um sistema que precisa fazer um upload de um arquivo para o bd. O sistema armazena o bin da imagem no banco ao invés de criar uma referência de um arquivo no servidor. Esse bin está corrompido, a imagem não abre.

Segue o código:

```
$anexo = $_FILES['anexo'];
$img_bin = addslashes(fread(fopen($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'], "r"), filesize($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'])));

$class_model->setImg_Bin($img_bin);
```

Comment: Como está configurado seu banco, principalmente a coluna que receberá os dados? Por que definiu a variável `$anexo` se posteriormente usou `$_FILES` de qualquer forma? Como verificou que os dados ficaram corrompidos?

Comment: É o seguinte: você conhece o Ocomon? Aqui na empresa utiliza-se este sistema, e foi desenvolvida uma página web com um formulário simples para o usuário criar uma ocorrência. O formulário do Ocomon salva corretamente, o do formulário salva com erro. Fiz testes com uma mesma imagem, o bin gerado são diferentes. Já verifiquei tudo o charset de ambas as páginas, tudo está igual. Obg.